# Intent data is missing on onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-bundle

I am creating an Intent and using putExtras I am adding an entity data which looks right but in onActivityResult(), some of the data is not received

Intent code:

Thanks
R

Update

Comment: onActivityResult in Fragment or in Activity?

Comment: It is a Fragment

Comment: I am getting rest of the data only the data in the setCustAnalValues is null.

Comment: Did you use startActivityForResult() when you started the activity? You can read https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Yes I did, I am getting all the data except that setCustAnalValues which is set to null

Comment: I see no setCustAnalValues to begin with. Please post all code as text. No images please.

Comment: You are using all kinds of constant values which we dont know of. You should not do that.

Comment: I suspect the parceling code in `AccountSearchEntity` is the problem. Please post the source for that class.

Comment: @BenP. Bang on mate, I missed to add the variable to the parcel. let me see if that fixes that issue. you are a champ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a `Parcelable` value through an `Intent` causes **some** of the information in that object to "disappear", the problem is almost always in the parceling/unparceling code of that class. Double-check to make sure that you're correctly saving and restoring all fields.

### Update

In your posted code for `SetFilterEntity`, there is only one constructor: the one that takes a `Parcel`. Simply add the default constructor to this class:

```
public SetFilterEntity() {
    // init values or just leave them default
}
```

Comment: Hello Ben, i have done the parceling but when i try to get an instance of it it SetFilterEntity setFilterEntity = new SetFilterEntity(); it complains SetFilterEntity(android.os.Parcel) has protected access in '....SetFilterENtity'. do you want update my question with a bit more code from both entities?

Comment: Hello Ben, updated with the entities I am using, If I am doing anything wrong please do let me know.